# Detecting the two Vector3 that determine the bottom-edge of the side of a box-collider that had collision (with C#)

Tags: c#, collision-detection, geometry, collision-resolution, vertex

So, I understand that plenty of questions have been posted on how to detect which side of a Box Collider had collision. However, what I am trying to achieve is a little different.

I want to find out, using the most efficient way possible (and avoiding RayCast if at all possible), which are the two Vector3 that determine the bottom-edge of the side of the Box Collider that had the collision (notice: in my case collision can never happen at the top or bottom faces of the Box Collider).

In the figure below, I illustrate the situation.

[image]

Notice the the Box Collider is in black wireframe representation, with blue faces being the ones that had collision in 4 different cases. The two Vector3 of the bottom-edges of the faces that had collision (which are what I want to know in the end) are in red.

PS: I don't know which face had the collision. Also, notice that in the above representation, Y axis is the vertical one.

Comment: I don't understand the illustration. What do the red dots represent?

Comment: They represent the bottom corners of the face that had collision.

Comment: There are some unclear things.
1. What is "bottom"?
2. In what form do you get the hit information?